# how to validate email in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, email, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a mvc 5 project .in contact us page I want user to send admin his / her emaiul address .so I want to validate email in javascript on that page .I wrote some code that does not work properly. I want you to help me plesae.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function f1() {
        var inputText = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var mailformat = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if (inputText.value.match(mailformat)) {
            document.form1.text1.focus();

        }
        else {
            alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
            document.form1.text1.focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And what does "code that does not work properly" actually mean?

Comment: BTW: TLDs can have more than 4 characters. An example might be `.museum` or `.rocks`.

Comment: What do you mean by not working properly?

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: If your using asp.net-mvc, then why are you not using the `[EmailAddress]` attribute on you property and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` so you get server and client side validation

Comment: Completely it does not work.I want to use client - side validation

Comment: you dont't want value in `if (inputText.value.match(mailformat))` because inputText is already a value so   `if (inputText.match(mailformat))` is correct... down below see my answer

Comment: @basloogh, What does not work? Using `[EmailAddress]` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` gives you both client side and more importantly server side validation, which you now need to also implement manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = ([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7});
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: Hi, this answer is a coppy from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript/46181#46181

Answer (score 0):

A basic HTML and JS working code for validating email with JS is given here for u-

```js
function validateForm()
{
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
    {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Valid e-mail address");
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Think, u have your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="form" action="#" onSubmit="return f1()" method="POST">
    <input type="email">
</form>
<script>
function f1(){
    var email = document.forms["form"]["Email"].value;
    var regex = /^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-_\\.]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)@([0-9a-zA-Z]([-_\\.]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)[\\.]([a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/;
    if(!regex.test(email)){
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
        return false;
    }
}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `inputText.value` only `inputText` like this

```html
<input type="text" id="email" />
<input type="submit" onClick="f1()"/>


<script language="javascript">
    function f1() {
        console.log(document.getElementById("email").value);
        var inputText = document.getElementById("email").value;
      console.log(inputText)
        var mailformat = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if (inputText.match(mailformat)) { // <<<<<<< here
            //document.form1.text1.focus();
            alert("correct")

        }
        else {
            alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
            document.form1.text1.focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
</script>
```